# How to combine column in aws quicksight

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-quicksight

I have

```
Year  Month Day
int   int   int
2021  10    21
2021  10    22
.....
```

I want to combine as whole date 2021-10-21
is this possible in quicksight?

how I can parse to date and create separate column as

```
date
2021-10-21
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your data set you will need to create a calculated field, as your columns are integers you will need to convert them to strings and concatenate them similar to Marisa's answer

```
parseDate(concat(toString({Month}), '/', toString({Day}), '/', toString({Year})), 'MM/dd/yyyy')
```

Would create what I think you are looking for

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this by concatenating the date pieces into a string, and then using the parseDate function.  I just tried it with parseDate(concat('10', '/', '21','/','2021'), 'MM/dd/yyyy') and it worked.